# React router v4 broswer history not working with code splitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router-v4

When using hash history code splitting works with react router but now i'm about to go into production and i want to switch to browser-history it gives an error when i try to change route, example if i try going to the login route 127.0.0.1:8080/auth/login :

> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/3.bundle.js' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled.

and

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Loading chunk 3 failed. (error:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/3.bundle.js)
>       at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete (bootstrap:108)

This is my router

```
<Router history={history}>
    <ConnectApp />
</Router>
```

Connect app:

```
 <Switch>
    {/* Front end */}
    <Route path="/" component={AsyncHome} exact />
    <Route path="/post/:id" component={AsyncPost} exact />

    {/* authentication */}
    <Route path="/auth/:section" component={AsyncLogin} exact />

    {/* Backend */}
    <PrivateRoute path="/admin/:path" component={AsyncAdmin} exact />
    <PrivateRoute
        path="/admin/edit-post/:id"
        component={AsyncEditPost}
        exact
    />

    <Route component={Err404} />
</Switch>
```

history.js:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory({
    // add configurations here
});
```

webpack.dev.config.js

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        historyApiFallback: true
    }, 
    plugins: [
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
    ]
}
```

*If there is any more code to add please indicate in the comment

Thank you

Comment: What is your production webpack config?  Do you have the issue in dev?  Or only production?  You said the issue exists when you "go into production".

Comment: I've fixed it already. I didn't add `publicPath:"/"` in my config

Comment: You can answer your own question to help others, or edit mine to make it better for others.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `publicPath:"/"` to the config:

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        historyApiFallback: true
    }, 
    plugins: [
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
    ],

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/' // Add this line
    },
}
```